# What is the expectation of the function of a random variable conditioned on itself $\mathbb{E}[g(X)|X]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-probability

Assume that $X$ is a continuous random variable with distribution $f_X$. Let $x$ be the realization of $X$.

Let $g$ be a continuous function

What is $\mathbb{E}[g(X)|X]$?

Applying the definition, we have, $\mathbb{E}[g(X)|X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f_X(x|x) dx$. But what is $f_X(x|x)$?

$f_X(x|x) = f_X(x,x)/f_X(x) = f_X(x)/f_X(x) = 1, \forall x \text{ such that } f_X(x) > 0$.

---

So is it true that,
$\mathbb{E}[g(X)|X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) dx, \forall x  \text{ such that } f_X(x) > 0?$

Comment: Your computation is not correct.  If you want to do it this way, you should define $h(x)=E[g(X)|X=x]$. Now the pdf $f_{X|X=x}(t)=\delta(t-x)$, an impulse function at the point $x$. Then $h(X)$ is $E[g(X)|X].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the random variable $g(X)$ is $\sigma(X)-$measurable since $g$ is a continuous function. Then a property of the conditional expectation is that if $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}-$measurable then $$\mathbb{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}] = Y \hspace{4mm}a.s.$$
So in your case
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)|X] = g(X)  \hspace{4mm}a.s.$$

Comment: Minor typo...you mean $g(X)$.

Comment: Where does the almost surely come from?

Comment: @SanjayGupta The way functions are defined in probability and measure theory is that two functions are said to be equal if they are equal almost surely. Basically it ensures that vectors are well defined in the normed space.

Comment: @AndrewShedlock Thank you. Could you offer a reference? i am reading Durrett's probability book and he does not define conditional expectation with almost surely. Although I'm positive that yours is more explicit and correct